# User authenticating but not staying logged in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

My Stack:

- Laravel Version: 5.3.9
- PHP Version: 7.0.8
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15
- Redis

I am using the Laravel auth:make scaffolding and when I login I am redirected to the correct page, but when I try to navigate to another page, I am redirected to login. I take a look at the debugbar and for the web routes auth, it says that I am logged in as a guest.

I created a route at `/test-login` that has this code:

`Auth::attempt(['email' => 'email@email.com', 'password' => 'password']);`

and I am logged in until I go to another page. For some reason, the session doesn't seem to be persisting for authentication. However, it appears that tokens are persisting in the session.

I tried installing a fresh copy of Laravel and moving all of the files that I edited over to that install and it still doesn't work, so it must be something in one of my files, I just can'y figure out what. I also uninstalled `predis/predis` because that was around the time I noticed some issues - no luck. For the session, I now have it using file instead of Redis. Any ideas?

Steps To Reproduce:

1. Login from the /login path
2. I am redirected to the correct page upon successful login
3. I try and navigate to another page
4. I am redirected back to login

Comment: Which session driver are you using?

Comment: @Carl I am now using `file` as the session driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found it... Dumb mistake on my part. For the logout link in my nav partial, I had

`{{ Auth::logout() }}`

Which logged me out since every page included the nav partial. Well... it happened and I spent too much time looking for it too.